# What's wrong with my makefile, last line never execute?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have to create a makefile that create the program `prog` that depends on three modules.

I create this makefile :

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall

all : prog

prog : prog.o mod1.o mod2.o Mod3.o
prog.o : prog.c
mod1.o : mod1.c mod1.h
mod2.o : mod2.c mod2.h
Mod3.o : Mod3.c Mod3.h

    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog.o mod1.o mod2.o Mod3.o -o prog

clean :
    rm prog
    rm *.o
```

My problem is that this line ­`Mod3.o : Mod3.c Mod3.h` never been launch. I mean, the last line never been execute, whatever it is. Any clue ?

Another question, does `prog.o` should be `prog.c mod1.h mod2.h Mod3.h` or the way I made is ok ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `$(CC) ....` must be directly behind `prog :`

```
prog : prog.o mod1.o mod2.o Mod3.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) prog.o mod1.o mod2.o Mod3.o -o prog

prog.o : prog.c
mod1.o : mod1.c mod1.h
mod2.o : mod2.c mod2.h
Mod3.o : Mod3.c Mod3.h
```

The other question can only be answered by yourself: is it neccessary to recompile prog.c whenever mod1.h or mod2.h change or not?